# Give unique IDs to Distinct names sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a sql server table containing names:

```
Serial  Name
1      Roger
2      John
3      John
4      Mike
5      Roger
6      John
7      Mike
```

I want to insert a UID column that will have unique IDs for unique names. So, it should look like,

```
Serial  Name    UID
1      Roger     1
2      John      2
3      John      2
4      Mike      3
5      Roger     1
6      John      2
7      Mike      3
```

Can anyone please help me with the query.

Comment: What have you attempted yourself? Please understand that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: is ID determined in order by Serial or Name, or doesn't matter?

Comment: Doesnt matter, it has to be unique for unique names

Comment: @Star_Kid any special reason behind this? Other way which you could easily be done that with key's relationship (Primary-Foreign Key)

Comment: With "insert a UID column", do you mean to add a column to the table, then update? Or just a select with that calculated field?

Comment: @LukStorms: Yes, update the table to have a new column having unique Ids

Comment: @PrashantPimpale: The same name has different attributes and would like to access all such attributes by using the unique ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add the column to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD [UID] INT NULL;

ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD constraint fk_yourtable_uid_id foreign key ([UID]) references yourtable([Serial]);
```

Then you can update the UID with the minimum `Serial` ID per Name.

```
UPDATE t
SET [UID] = q.[UID]
FROM yourtable t
JOIN
(
  SELECT Name, MIN([Serial]) AS [UID]
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY Name
) q ON q.Name = t.Name
WHERE (t.[UID] IS NULL OR t.[UID] != q.[UID]) -- Repeatability
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: @star_kid Thanks. Btw, the added WHERE clause is to make the update repeatable. So that when you run it afterwards that it'll only update the records that need to be updated.

Comment: Do you think there is a way that could provide same UID to same dataset for each time we run the query.
Currently, each time I run the query for the same dataset, it provides different unique UID.

Comment: @star_kid If new records are added to that table then the only way the minimum UID can change is when the record with that minimum Serial is deleted. Then another record would have the minimum Serial and this SQL will update the UID for the related records.  In that case you could perhaps in the process that deletes records avoid deleting the records where the Serial = UID?

Comment: @star_kid Or maybe you reload that table completely every time? If that Serial is an IDENTITY you'd get different Serials for the records. In that case you'd might want to change the reload from a `delete all or drop table then insert all` to something like a `MERGE`. So that you'd only update the existing & insert the new.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by name) as unique_id
from t;
```

If you want to maintain the original ordering by the first column, then you can use that:

```
select t.*, min(serial) over (partition by name) as unique_id
from t;
```

This will have gaps.  You can combine these to get a unique, gap-less sequence:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by seqnum) as unique_id
from (select t.*, min(serial) over (partition by name) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

This method has the advantage that it is stable -- assuming that the first column is an identity column (so new names added over time would have higher `serial` values than existing names).

Answer (score 1):

To select it on the fly, use this:

```
with CTE as
(
select name, dense_rank() over (order by name) as rn
from MyTable
)
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.rn
from MyTable t1
inner join CTE t2
on t2.name = t1.name
```

To bake it in, create a new table of names with an `identity(1,0)` column and add new names to this list (thrown together for inspiration)

```
create table name_uid
(
id      int identity(1,0) not null,
name    varchar(50)
)

insert into name_uid (name)
select distinct name 
from mytable

alter table mytable
add the_uid int

alter table
add constraint fk_name_uid foreign key (the_uid) references name_uid(id)

update t1
set t1.the_uid = t2.id
from Mytable t1
inner join name_uid t2
on t1.name = t2.name

create trigger tr_uid on MyTable
for insert
as
declare @name varchar
declare @exist int
declare @uid  int
begin
select @name = i.name from inserted i;
select @exist = case when exists (select 1 from name_uid where name = @name) then 1 else 0 end;
begin
if @exist = 0
insert into name_uid (name) values (@name);
end;
select @uid = select id from name_uid where name = @name;
update MyTable;
set the_uid = @uid;
go
```